# Docusign Accounts API bug

Tags: docusignapi

We are developing feature that allows users to add identity verification to envelopes. And there's a checkbox which is called "Allow recipient to provide phone number"
We need to decide when to show that checkbox, because not all accounts have access to the checkbox.
From documentation (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/accounts/listsettings/) I see that there's phoneAuthRecipientMayProvidePhoneNumber field which allows to determine that thing.

When I open the page for envelope creation I can see that the checkbox is available but API returns false value for that field. So we can't really decide do we need to show that field or not.
It seems like a bug in API.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look into this issue and I see that I'm getting the same behaviour - "phoneAuthRecipientMayProvidePhoneNumber" is always returning "false" for me as well, so I believe that you're correct that there's a product issue here. Can you email go-live@docusign.com with a link to this question and reference case number 07556985, which is a case created for this issue? Once you do that, I can create a ticket for this behaviour and let you know as it progresses.